# SQL get different column result depending on another column value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Have table like this:

```
`id`     `race_day`  `racer_nr`  `racer_name`           `racer_class`    `start_time`               `arrive_time`               `spent_time`     `total`     `yellow_card`   `bonus`     `penalties`     `comment`
1           1           313       'racer name 1'         ''              '2018-02-04 10:00:00'      '2018-02-04 10:57:00'       '00:57:00'       '00:57:00'     0               0           0               ''
2           1           135       'racer name 2'         ''              '2018-02-04 10:00:00'      '2018-02-04 13:59:55'       '03:59:55'       '03:59:55'     0               0           5               ''
3           1           55        'racer name 3'         ''              '2018-02-04 10:00:00'      '2018-02-04 11:59:50'       '01:59:50'       '01:59:50'     0               0           0               ''
4           1           315       'racer name 4'     ''              '2018-02-04 10:00:00'      '2018-02-04 10:01:40'       '00:01:40'       '00:01:40'     0               20          3600            ''
17          2           313       'racer name 1'         ''              '2018-02-05 10:00:00'      '2018-02-05 10:57:00'       '00:57:00'       '00:57:00'     0               0           0               ''
18          2           135       'racer name 2'         ''              '2018-02-05 10:00:00'      '2018-02-05 13:59:55'       '03:59:55'       '03:59:55'     0               0           0               ''
19          2           55        'racer name 3'         ''              '2018-02-05 10:00:00'      '2018-02-05 11:59:50'       '01:59:50'       '01:59:50'     0               0           0               ''
20          2           315       'racer name 4'     ''              '2018-02-05 10:00:00'      '2018-02-05 10:01:40'       '00:01:40'       '00:01:40'     0               0           0               ''
21          3           313       'racer name 1'         ''              '2018-02-06 10:00:00'      '2018-02-06 10:57:00'       '00:57:00'       '00:57:00'     0               0           0               ''
22          3           135       'racer name 2'         ''              '2018-02-06 10:00:00'      '2018-02-06 13:59:55'       '03:59:55'       '03:59:55'     0               0           0               ''
23          3           55        'racer name 3'         ''              '2018-02-06 10:00:00'      '2018-02-06 11:59:50'       '01:59:50'       '01:59:50'     0               0           0               ''
24          3           315       'racer name 4'     ''              '2018-02-06 10:00:00'      '2018-02-06 10:01:40'       '00:01:40'       '00:01:40'     0               15          3600            ''
25          4           313       'racer name 1'         ''              '2018-02-07 10:00:00'      '2018-02-07 10:57:00'       '00:57:00'       '00:57:00'     0               0           0               ''
26          4           135       'racer name 2'         ''              '2018-02-07 10:00:00'      '2018-02-07 13:59:55'       '03:59:55'       '03:59:55'     0               0           0               ''
27          4           55        'racer name 3'         ''              '2018-02-07 10:00:00'      '2018-02-07 11:59:50'       '01:59:50'       '01:59:50'     0               0           0               ''
28          4           315       'racer name 4'     ''              '2018-02-07 10:00:00'      '2018-02-07 10:01:40'       '00:01:40'       '00:01:40'     0               0           0               ''
29          5           313       'racer name 1'         ''              '2018-02-08 10:00:00'      '2018-02-08 10:57:00'       '00:57:00'       '00:57:00'     0               0           0               ''
30          5           135       'racer name 2'         ''              '2018-02-08 10:00:00'      '2018-02-08 13:59:55'       '03:59:55'       '03:59:55'     0               0           0               ''
31          5           55        'racer name 3'         ''              '2018-02-08 10:00:00'      '2018-02-08 11:59:50'       '01:59:50'       '01:59:50'     0               0           0               ''
32          5           315       'racer name 4'     ''              '2018-02-08 10:00:00'      '2018-02-08 10:01:40'       '00:01:40'       '00:01:40'     0               0           0               ''
```

and sql query like this:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    race_day, 
    racer_nr, 
    racer_name, 
    arrive_time, 
    spent_time, 
    sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(spent_time)+penalties-bonus)) AS total_time_spent, 
    SUM(penalties) AS total_penalties, 
    SUM(bonus) as total_bonus, 
    yellow_card 
FROM `race_days` 
WHERE 
     `race_day` = 1 OR `race_day` = 2 OR `race_day` = 3 OR `race_day` = 4 OR `race_day` = 5
GROUP BY racer_nr 
ORDER BY total_time_spent ASC
```

and I got all data as I want.. 
but if I want to get arrive_time of different race_day I get only first date  (race_day =1)

i.e. 
counting totals of race_day = 2 my query would be like this:

```
SELECT 
    id, 
    race_day, 
    racer_nr, 
    racer_name, 
    arrive_time, 
    spent_time, 
    sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(spent_time)+penalties-bonus)) AS total_time_spent, 
    SUM(penalties) AS total_penalties, 
    SUM(bonus) as total_bonus, 
    yellow_card 
FROM `race_days` 
WHERE 
     `race_day` = 1 OR `race_day` = 2
GROUP BY racer_nr 
ORDER BY total_time_spent ASC
```

and I can't get arrive_time (also and start_time) of race_day = 2..

So my desired result of race_day = 2 should be like this:

```
`id`, `race_day`, `racer_nr`, `racer_name`, `arrive_time`, `spent_time`, `total_time_spent`, `total_penalties`, `total_bonus`, `yellow_card`
4, 1, 315, 'racer name 4', '2018-02-05 10:01:40', '00:01:40', '01:03:00', '3600', '20', 0
1, 1, 313, 'racer name 1', '2018-02-05 10:57:00', '00:57:00', '01:54:00', '0', '0', 0
3, 1, 55, 'racer name 3', '2018-02-05 11:59:50', '01:59:50', '03:59:40', '0', '0', 0
2, 1, 135, 'racer name 2', '2018-02-05 13:59:55', '03:59:55', '07:59:55', '5', '0', 0
```

any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: Edit your question and provide desired results.

Comment: u have written that you got desired result from running first query . but on which platform did u run it ??
as per my understating the first query u have written should throw error and not run . .

Answer (score 0):

The `select` clause should always match the `group by` clause in an aggregation query.  So you should be starting with:

```
SELECT racer_nr, 
       sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(spent_time)+penalties-bonus)) AS total_time_spent, 
       SUM(penalties) AS total_penalties, 
       SUM(bonus) as total_bonus
FROM race_days rd
WHERE race_day in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY racer_nr 
ORDER BY total_time_spent ASC;
```

I have no idea what you intend the other (non aggregated) columns to be.  However, they should either be arguments to aggregation function or in the `group by` clause.

For instance, if you wanted a separate row for each `race_day`, you would do:

```
SELECT racer_nr, race_day, MIN(arrive_time),
       sec_to_time(SUM(time_to_sec(spent_time)+penalties-bonus)) AS total_time_spent, 
       SUM(penalties) AS total_penalties, 
       SUM(bonus) as total_bonus
FROM race_days rd
WHERE race_day in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
GROUP BY racer_nr, race_day
ORDER BY total_time_spent ASC;
```